# How to sort vector of pairs <float, string> regardless of string

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort `std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>>` in ascending order.

Although using `std::sort` works, I found out the strings affect the order if the floats have the same values.

I would like to sort the vector regardless of the string so the former element always gets located first than latter ones.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>> vec;
    vec = {{1, "e"}, {1, "d"}, {1, "c"}, {1, "b"}, {1, "a"}};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (auto i : vec)
        std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << '\n';
}
```

**The Result I Get :** (alphabetical order when value ties)

```
1, a
1, b
1, c
1, d
1, e
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**The Result I Want :** (former element first when value ties)

```
1, e
1, d
1, c
1, b
1, a
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::pair` has it's comparing operators overloaded ([See the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp))

By default, `operator <` for `std::pair` compares first elements, if they are equal, then second elements.

You should provide your own predicate and use `std::stable_sort` to preserve the order of elements if first elements in pair are equal.

```
std::stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                 [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a.first < b.first;});
```

Comment: I think you can do `const auto& a` etc. and reduce verbosity a bit

Comment: @M.M Going directly to universal references is even shorter.

Comment: `auto&&` would be using universal references, or forwarding references. Anyway, it's 4 characters shorter, at the cost of not enforcing non-mutation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably searching for `std::stable_sort`. It sorts elements while preserving the order of equivalents.

Comment: that won't help when sorting `std::pair`s due to the way the [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) is defined for it

Comment: Could be achieved through use of a lambda

Comment: it needs stable sort and a comparator that only compares the pairs first

Answer (score -1):

You can provide a compare function to [**std::sort**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Like

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);
```

In your case the compare function can be:

```
bool comp(const std::pair<float, std::string>&a, const std::pair<float, std::string>&b){
    if(a.first == b.first) return 0;
    else return a.first < b.first;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://ideone.com/33VQQs)

Comment: you will still need [`stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to guarantee keeping the order of equivalent items.

Comment: Simply `return a.first < b.first;` is sufficient.